# LPC12xx I2C vector to a service routine

Tags: c, embedded

I have some problems with implementing a "vector to a service routine" in C.

Right now I implement the IRQ-Handler of a I2C interface like this:

```
    void I2C0_IRQHandler(void)
    {
        statusCode = LPC_I2C->STAT;
        switch ( statusCode ) { (...) }
    }
```

With many status code this is slow, cause all the cases have to be visited.

The user manual of the LPC12xx microcontroller gives a hint:

> If the status code is used as a vector to service
>   routines, then the routines are displaced by eight address locations. 
>   Eight bytes of code is sufficient for most of the service routines

So I should write some handler-functions with exactly 8 bytes of code size each and put them at the correct memory location:

```
0xABCDEF00: handler_for_code_0x00
0xABCDEF08: handler_for_code_0x08
(...)
0xABCDEF90: handler_for_code_0x90
```

In the interrupt handler I

1. add the status code to a memory offset (here 0xABCDEF00)
2. cast this address to a function pointer
3. and call the function.

Do I have this right? how could I implement this in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you determined that the `switch` slows down with additional cases?

Most compilers will generate a jump table that is deterministic and certainly does not "visit" each case.  You may help the compiler generate efficient code by ensuring the cases are numerically sequential, and not sparsely separated (i.e. no gaps between values).

There are only 32 possible status codes, so an exhaustive switch with a case for all codes (even if the cases are empty) is probably not prohibitive.  The first three bits of `STAT` are unused, so if you first shift the status right by three bits so that the status values start from zero, that too may enable the compiler to generate more efficient code.  I would in fact expect it to generate a jump table equivalent to @Dill's suggestion (which was going to be my suggestion).

The following is an idiomatic example that is trivially optimised by most compilers, just add code to those cases you explicitly want to handle.  If your compiler does not generate deterministic code from this try experimenting with the compiler optimisation levels. However if it cannot do that, I'd consider getting a different compiler!

```
void I2C0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    switch( LPC_I2C->STAT >> 3 ) 
    { 
        case 0x01 :
            break ;
        case 0x02 :
            break ;
        case 0x03 :
            break ;
        case 0x04 :
            break ;
        case 0x05 :
            break ;
        case 0x06 :
            break ;
        case 0x07 :
            break ;
        case 0x08 :
            break ;
        case 0x09 :
            break ;
        case 0x0a :
            break ;
        case 0x0b :
            break ;
        case 0x0c :
            break ;
        case 0x0d :
            break ;
        case 0x0e :
            break ;
        case 0x0f :
            break ;
        case 0x10:
            break ;
        case 0x11 :
            break ;
        case 0x12 :
            break ;
        case 0x13 :
            break ;
        case 0x14 :
            break ;
        case 0x15 :
            break ;
        case 0x16 :
            break ;
        case 0x17 :
            break ;
        case 0x18 :
            break ;
        case 0x19 :
            break ;
        case 0x1a :
            break ;
        case 0x1b :
            break ;
        case 0x1c :
            break ;
        case 0x1d :
            break ;
        case 0x1e :
            break ;
        case 0x1f :
            break ;
    }
}
```

Comment: the >> 3 does the trick. Now the jump-table is built by the compiler and the code runs faster, which was not done due to space-optimization with the very sparse jump-table. Ill implement the ASM version when im bored just to see some more ticks spared :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be tough to do this in C. I can think of two solutions:

(1) use asm to create the table of 8 byte handler functions where each handler is just a jump to a C function, e.g.

```
org 0xABCDEF00
jmp handler_for_code_0x00
org 0xABCDEF08
jmp handler_for_code_0x01
...
org 0xABCDEF90
jmp handler_for_code_0x1f
```

(2) instead of using the vectored interrupts, keep your current scheme but create a jump table using function pointers (this assumes that your compiler is not already smart enough to generate a jump table from your switch statement), e.g.

```
typedef void (*handler_fn)(void);

static void handler_for_code_0x00(void) { ... }

static void handler_for_code_0x01(void) { ... }

...

static void handler_for_code_0x1f(void) { ... }

static void handler_for_code_unused(void) { ... }

const handler_fn handler_table[NUM_STATUS_CODE] = {
    handler_for_code_0x00,
    handler_for_code_0x01,
    handler_for_code_unused,
    handler_for_code_0x03,
    handler_for_code_0x04,
    ...
    handler_for_code_0x1d
    handler_for_code_unused,
    handler_for_code_0x1f
};

void I2C0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    statusCode = LPC_I2C->STAT >> 3 ;  // Get table index
    handler_table[statusCode]();
}
```

Comment: if its not possible to align the C functions directly in memory giving them 8 words of code size each maybe its best to implement the functions in ASM. So i got minimum codesize and maximum speed.
in C I could use your version 2) but use the fact that all status codes differ by 8 and shift them so that the lookup table isnt sparse anymore. I think ill do that. thank you.

Comment: OK - one other possibility - you *might* be able to write all your vectored handlers as small C functions and then use linker commands to locate these at the right absolute addresses, but it could be tricky.

Comment: @Dill:  They do not need to be aligned in memory and restricted to 8 bytes - that would only be necessary if using the "trick" mentioned in the manual - this is a different more flexible method and far less restrictive, and the only practical method if not using assembler.

Comment: Note that only bits 7:3 of the STAT register are used, so the table need only be 32 elements long and you need to shift statusCode right before indexing the table.  I made the change for you.  Depending on the compiler, you may need to do more than just declare the table const to have it placed in ROM; check the map file to check that it is suitably located.